# Recover accidentally closed Opera window and its tabs after restarting

Tags: opera, browser-tabs

I accidentally closed an instance of Opera with multiple tabs. There was another window with a couple of tabs running.

I have closed and restarted Opera in the hope it will retrieve the windows at startup (it usually asks if I want to continue from last time).

Is there a way I can retrieve my closed window with all the tabs? I cannot see them in the history either, probably because when I switched on my PC the Internet connection was down and the pages didn't load.

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl-Shift-T`?

Answer (score 7):

I'm using **Opera 35**, and the `Recently closed` menu is under a dedicated button next to the window controls:

[image: recently closed menu]

Comment: This option doesn't show closed tabs before restart.

Comment: This if for tabs, not windows.

Answer (score 6):

Opera periodically saves a backup of your session between restarts. If you are quick enough, you can retrieve the backup before it is overwritten. Don't open or close any more tabs in Opera until you do the following.

On Windows, have a look at "%APPDATA%\Opera\Opera\sessions\". If you are using a different installation directory or you are on a different operating system, you will have to find your profile path. Type "opera:about" into your address bar.

You should have an "autosave.win" and an "autosave.win.bak" in the "sessions" folder.

Copy both files, and back them up somewhere. You can close now Opera, which will cause both files to be overwritten.

Now, return to "%APPDATA%\Opera\Opera\sessions\", rename "autosave.win" to "autosave0.win.bak" and "autosave.win.bak" to "autosave.win".

Finally, re-open Opera.

Remember, next time, you should carefully backup your sessions using "Opera Menu > Tabs and Windows > Sessions > Save This Session..." or "Right click inside of the Bookmarks Manager > Bookmark All Open Pages".

Comment: FWIW, I don't find that folder existing anywhere, nor that file, even using a search tool running as Admin (for that, I love Ultrasearch from Jam Software). This is in 2016, regarding this answer from 2010/2013. I'm on Opera 35.0, on Windows 10, in case this may help anyone else who goes looking for it. Consider instead the answer offered by Mike below, in 2015, for another file and location I did find.

Comment: This didn't work, even though my 2 `autosave.win` files were from two days ago. Opera 40. I had the same problem, I had detached a single tab into its own window, which I almost never do, then forgot about it and closed the main window thereby losing all my saved tabs.

Answer (score 6):

Meanwhile (Opera 25.0) there is a built-in feature for retrieving a recently closed window (and it's tabs).

`Opera Menu` > `Recently closed`

(Great feature btw ^^)

Comment: Thanks, Levit! That pointer really saved my bacon. I had opened two windows (doing some work in one, separate from the main one where I keep all my other tabs). I was shutting down, and closed that main window, then saw this other one (with just a couple tabs) still open. I was aghast that if I closed it, Opera may only reopen to THAT window (and its tabs, losing all the others). Thankfully, this feature reopened my "main" window. I don't find it in the opera menu, though, but (in 35.0) in that curious icon at the top right, left of the minimize icon.

Comment: This saved my hour too. The only minor difference: I am on Linux  and for me it was `Opera Menu > History > Recently closed`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help anyone else, but when I could not find any files in the session folder, I did discover this one:

```
C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Last Session
```

I opened it in Notepad++ and found all the URL's that were in the lost session. There was a lot of garbage and url duplication, but it let me recover *months* of research and work resources that I thought I had lost. Just search the file for "http" and copy/paste the appropriate stuff into the browser.

And look for ways to save those urls.

Answer (score 1):

If autosave.win.bak doesn't contain your session either, try to recover as soon as possible the most recent (and biggest) autosave.win in `..\Opera\Opera\sessions` directory using an undelete program (e.g. [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva)).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that the humble "history" feature at least records the URLs that you hit recently, though not the full page state.  It should persist for at least 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

In Opera version 49:

1. Go to `%APPDATA%\Opera Software\Opera Stable`.
   Notes:

   - `%APPDATA%` is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming`
   - `%USERPROFILE%`, of course, is your home directory,
     typically `C:\Users\YourUserName`;
     although it may be elsewhere;
     e.g., `D:\Users\YourUserName`
   - The `%USERPROFILE%\AppData` folder is typically hidden.
2. DELETE (or move / rename to a backup): 
   `Current Session` and `Current Tabs`.
3. RENAME: `Last Session` and `Last Tabs`
   to `Current Session` and `Current Tabs`.
4. Start OPERA.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that opera

- Saves "user closed tabs"
- Saves "user closed windows"

within a period as far in the past as

- a period set for Opera to save browsing history.

My recent discovery is that

- For "system closed tabs" or "system closed windows" upon forced restart by Windows Update
- AND for "application closed tabs" or "application closed windows" upon forced restart by Opera Update,

Opera does not retain a log of closed tabs or windows so I could not reopen closed windows that contained about 20 tabs.  However, I could see tabs and windows I closed by "user action" that took place before and after the forced restart of Opera browser.

I tested the scenarios by installing and uninstalling Office to cause system reboot while other chromium browsers were running: including Google Chrome and Yandex Browser.  They both lost non-user closed tabs and windows.

Firefox seem to save all tabs and windows, but it becomes very slow when many tabs are open.

I tested Edge the same way, but the possibility of recovery was case-by-case with the browser and I cannot figure out rules behind its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any way to do this in Opera (40.0). However, the tabs, with their history can be restored in Chrome.

1. Go into Chrome settings and make sure "On startup" -> "Continue where you left off" is selected.
2. Close Chrome
3. Open Chrome's data folder "...AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\" and delete the two files "Current Session" and "Current Tabs".
4. Copy the file "Last Session" from "%appdata%\Opera Software\Opera Stable\" into Chrome's data folder and rename it to "Current Session".
5. Start Chrome

Your tabs should now show up.

Comment: This is a little confusing.  Are you saying you can restore Opera using Chrome, you can recover the Opera tabs into Chrome so at least they aren't lost, or you're just observing that Chrome can do this so the solution is to switch to Chrome?

Comment: I'm saying: As long as you haven't overwritten opera's "Last Session" file (by opening and closing Opera) then you can restore, the tabs that you lost in Chrome.

I apologise if I wasn't clear, but doing this this will of course overwrite Chromes current tabs. And, if you want the tabs back in Opera, you will have to copy the URL's, from Chrome to Opera, manually.

Comment: It doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this issue for years, and Opera out of the box just doesn't support this, so if you're reading this having lost all your tabs, unless you have a backup of the correct folders in %appdata%\Opera Software\Opera Stable\ and can overwrite the existing profile you are out of luck.

However, I have very fortunately discovered that one of my plugins "The great suspender" - which enables me to keep tabs in the browser which don't consume resources - automatically keeps backups of your sessions and can reopen them!

So my answer is, install the great suspender plugin, and review the sessions it creates. You might find it very handy one day.

Answer (score -1):

Solved for Opera 48.0.2685.35

Go to C:\Users\UrCompName\AppData(hidden folder see below)\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable

Here find and save as a copy two files before u delete them, they have no extension: Last Session and Last Tabs (approx 4 MB and 368 KB) Delete them. 
Start Opera. Enjoy!!!

---

If u kitty scary, play with Opera (portable version) on USB, as a test.
USB X:\opera\profile\data and DEL 4 files: Current Session, Current Tabs, Last Session and Last Tabs(r empty)
Paste from PC (crashed/closed) to USB two files: Current Session, Current Tabs and start thru Opera Launcher on USB ->launcher.exe (very slow, just USB)

---

PC AppData Folder is hidden! go to Folder Options(menu)-> Show hidden files, folders and drives(choosen)->Apply->Ok

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you cannot even restore previous session. Get it from your backup.
Close Opera.
Go into C Drive username/AppData/Local/Opera Software and rename the folder Opera Stable as Bad Opera Stable
Go into C Drive username/AppData/Roaming/Opera Software and rename the folder Opera Stable as Bad Opera Stable
Go to the last backup that you made, 
In username/AppData/Local/Opera Software copy the Opera Stable folder and paste it into the same location on C Drive.
In username/AppData/Roaming/Opera Software copy the Opera Stable folder and paste it into the same location on C Drive.
Try it, it works but you miss the last day or two.